# Are unwrap()s under patterns optimized away?

Tags: performance, rust, pattern-matching

I have some code where I often use `unwrap()` under patterns, where I can be sure it won't panic. Some of those pieces are in performance-critical functions, so I was wondering if it would be a good idea to get rid of these `unwrap()`s in favor of unchecked variants of applicable functions. However, I didn't see any difference with `#[bench]` tests and the ASM for both variants looks pretty similar to me (though I'm not an expert).

It appears that Rust is able to optimize such cases away; am I right or should I use unchecked functions instead of `unwrap()`?

MCVE:

```
use self::Foo::*;
use self::Error::*;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Foo {
    Bar(Box<Foo>),
    Baz
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Error {
    NotBar
}

impl Foo {
    fn bar_mut_ref(&mut self) -> Result<&mut Foo, Error> {
        match *self {
            Bar(ref mut foo) => Ok(foo),
            _ => Err(NotBar)
        }
    }

    fn bar_mut_ref_unchecked(&mut self) -> &mut Foo {
        match *self {
            Bar(ref mut foo) => foo,
            _ => panic!("bar_mut_ref_unchecked() called on a non-Bar!")
        }
    }

    fn bazify(&mut self) {
        match *self {
            Bar(_) => { *self = Baz },
            _ => ()
        }
    }
}

fn do_stuff_with_foo(foo: &mut Foo) {
    match *foo {
        Bar(_) => {
            foo.bar_mut_ref().unwrap().bazify(); // is _unchecked() better here?
            // underscore was used because foo is assigned to a new value here
        },
        _ => {}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Bar(Box::new(Bar(Box::new(Baz))));
    do_stuff_with_foo(&mut foo);
    println!("{:?}", foo);
}
```

Comment: As for all micro-optimization questions: if it's not a problem, use the safe alternative.

Comment: @ildjarn: I did my check on [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org). I can see that the ASM you linked was compiled with a specific set of flags to reduce its size to a functional minimum; that's pretty handy.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: this makes sense, though in this case both variants are equally safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A more direct comparison](https://godbolt.org/g/SUfcRD) of the two approaches yields identical ASM, so at least for this simple example the answer appears to be: yes, such cases can be optimized away.

```
example::do_stuff_with_foo:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        push    rbx
        push    rax
        mov     rbx, qword ptr [rdi]
        test    rbx, rbx
        je      .LBB1_3
        cmp     qword ptr [rbx], 0
        je      .LBB1_3
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    core::ptr::drop_in_place
        mov     qword ptr [rbx], 0
.LBB1_3:
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Comment: Community Wiki does not make link answers acceptable. I would personally advise just posting a regular answer, and maybe list the assembly emitted stating that both cases yield it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. : Feel free to edit the answer into whatever format you think is more appropriate – _that's_ why it's CW. ;-]